# How i can add new item to the same node in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a new item to my list, I use firebase without user(email,password)

I have page for search and other to show detail , how i can add more detail for the same node , And i don't know which node you want to add a child to.

I want to add new items like this:-

Start with:

```
-vdjs43ndjufd87

     "name" : Jak

    "university" : Harvard
```

End with:

```
-vdjs43ndjufd87

     "name" : Jak

     "university" : Harvard

     "age" : 23
```

this code is not working with me:-

```
 let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key

 let post = ["uid": userID, "author": username, "title": title, "body": body]

let childUpdates = ["/posts/(key)": post, "/user-posts/(userID)/(key)/": post]

ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the id of post in which you want to add a new item. Otherwise there isn't any way to solve your problem. For example, you have a page with table view which shows list of posts. Also to populate cells of table you hold an array of posts. Every post object should have id property. When you select row in table you should get indexPath of it and get post from array with indexPath.row index. From selected post you get id and this is all. Now you have post id and you can download info about this post and also add some new items to node with this id.

```
ref.child("posts").child(postId).updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Comment: i have search bar that show results and when you choose name will go to another( view controller) show details for this name

Comment: so can i add new item like comments to this name?

Comment: You probably show result  table view so have to hold array of post object. When you choose table cell (when you choose name) you have to get post id from array and when you know post id you can add new item. Without id you can't. You can't just hold names in array, you have to create class Post and put inside some properties one of them should be id.

Comment: Yes On the results page you exit the data of the name you have chosen, how can I add another evaluation to the same ID?